# Trying to login into wordpress externally

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am sending a curl post from a script installed in a sub-directory to the wordpress installation installed in the root:

```
        $fields_string = 'username='.urlencode($my_username);

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);
```

The receiving file in the WP installation has:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../wp-load.php' );

// GET THE USERNAME FROM THE POST
$username = $_POST['username'];

// GET USER INFO. WE NEED THE ID!   
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

// SET THE COOKIE!
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, false, '' );
```

But it is not working. I can see in my logs that the post hits the second script, but when I open a new tab in the browser and visit the blog it is logged out. Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: Change POST to GET/REQUEST and also urldecode your username at your receiving script

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code to login into wordpress...    

 $username='admin';
 $password='dummyPassword';
 $postdata = 'log='. $username .'&pwd='. $password .'&wp-submit=Log%20In&redirect_to='. $adminUrl;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$adminUrl2);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $adminUrl1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
 $result = curl_exec ($ch);
 $end = strpos($result, 'Content-Type');
 $start = strpos($result, 'Set-Cookie');
 $parts = split('Set-Cookie: ',substr($result, $start, $end-$start));
 $cookies = array();
 foreach ($parts as $co) {
    $cd = split(';',$co);
    if (!empty($cd[0]))
    $cookies[] = $cd[0];
 }

 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode(';',$cookies));
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 $resultadmin = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 $domadmin = new DOMDocument;
 $domadmin->loadHTML($resultadmin);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! According to your snippet, I set `$adminUrl=http://example.com/wp-admin`, `$adminUrl1=http://example.com/my-other-script/login`, `$adminUrl2=http://example.com/wp-login.php`, but still no luck. I open another tab, go to wordpress, and it is logged out. I just want the member to be logged in into wp in the background seamlessly as they log in into script be. Please help.

Comment: What I what to do is that as they login into script 'B' located into a subfolder, they get loggeed in into wordpres. so when they visit the wordpress part, they dont have to re-login. Your input/suggestions are very much appreciated! I already got the simultaneous registration working, so every user has same user/pass in both wp and script 'B'

Comment: Give            $adminUrl ='http://example.com/wp-admin/&testcookie=1';      and   $adminUrl2 = 'http://example.com/wp-login.php/';            When you login to wordpress you also need to set cookie..